# How to test apache flume load balancing - Sink groups

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I am kind of newbie to apache flume , I have configured single tier agent with sink group -load balance manually , I would like to know how can i test the sink group load balancing ? any idea folks

Answer (score 0):

You can define two different sinks and mention them in the Sink Groups as below,

```
agent1.sinkgroups = g1
agent1.sinkgroups.g1.sinks = HDFS1 HDFS2
agent1.sinkgroups.g1.processor.type = load_balance
agent1.sinkgroups.g1.processor.backoff = true
agent1.sinkgroups.g1.processor.selector = round_robin
```

Here both of them are HDFS sinks.

You can mention the process selector (round_robin[default], random or custom selector) which defines how should the load be balanced between two sinks.

When you run the agent, you can see that two different set of data is stored in two respective HDFS paths(sinks).

Other two optional parameters are backoff and selector.maxTimeOut

You can refer this link for more info [Flume 1.6.0 User Guide](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#load-balancing-sink-processor)